# Need advance search in phonegap + jQuery?

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am making an app in phonegap + jQuery. Actually, I am able to search text from current page(having some data ). Now I need some concept.

Can we search a text from files which is save in internal memory of android/iOS. Can we do this using jQuery?

Can we search text in file which is stored in internal memory or data base?

As we see in iOS device if we search than it able to search from all file?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can do that, there are many ways for storing and reading data, if you are set on using files you can use this library https://github.com/torrmal/cordova-simplefilemanagement

you can also explore options like http://www.jstorage.info/

and there is this too:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html